# C# - Multiple LINQ query into One?

Tags: c#, linq

I have used two LINQ queries to manipulate a datatable and return the data that I want.  Effectively, the table has the following columns:

```
Group    Animal     Numbers
```

There can be multiple Animals within a single group, and multiple numbers assigned to a single animal.  Initially I want to calculate the range of the numbers for each specific animal, and then calculate an average range for each group.  With the output being the group number and then the average range.

I have the following two LINQ queries, that do work, however my question is, can this be merged into a single query, or , as they are distinct operations, should they be kept seperate for readability and testability?

```
 //Calculate range/delta for each number per animal
        var query = from data in Data.AsEnumerable()
                    group data by new { animal = data.Field<string>("animal"), gp = data.Field<string>("group") }
                        into g
                        orderby g.Key.gp
                        select new
                        {
                            animal = g.Key.animal,
                            gp = g.Key.gp,
                            delta = g.Max(c => Convert.ToDouble(c.Field<string>("numbers")))
                                    - g.Min(c => Convert.ToDouble(c.Field<string>("numbers")))

                        };

       //calculate average range/delta per group
        var temp = from q in query
                   group q by q.gp
                       into g
                       select new
                       {
                           gp = g.Key,
                           average = g.Average(c => c.delta)

                       };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you aren't forcing the first query to evaluate with a method like `ToArray()`, there's no advantage to combining these queries. I would leave them separate for readability.

Comment: Actually he is forcing the query to be evaluated by calling `AsEnumerable()` in the first query.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` doesn't force query evaluation. <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx>

Comment: The last sentence in the remarks section in the article you linked to is important.  True, calling `AsEnumerable()` doesn't immeadiately enumerate the `Data` entities.  It does however effect which implementation of `group` is used, Table<T> vs IEnumerable<T>.  This can have a HUGE impact on the SQL generated when it finally is evaluated.  For example, a `where` would not be evaluated on the server side.  All entities would be retrieved and the `where` would be done using Linq-to-Objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could first group the data by `group` and then, in a nested query, by `animal` to calculate the average of the deltas:

```
var result = from data in Data.AsEnumerable()
             group data by data.Field<string>("group") into g
             select new
             {
                 gp = g.Key,
                 average = (
                     from item in g
                     group item by data.Field<string>("animal") into f
                     select f.Max(c => double.Parse(c.Field<string>("numbers")))
                          - f.Min(c => double.Parse(c.Field<string>("numbers")))
                 ).Average()
             };
```